# How to create an async middleware between react-navigation routes

Tags: react-navigation

Is there a way to create a middleware that allows me to check something asynchronously then redirect to somewhere (Login for example) or just keep going to the desired route?

My specific use case, is to check if a token does not exists in an async local storage, then redirect to the login page.